# How to handle empty values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have to update a fairly large Access 2007 table (18 fields) from Excel 2007 using Excel VBA.  The trouble is many fields in the rows can have no value and to create an algorithm to change the SQL statement would be enormous, i.e. determine for each row which fields have to be in the UPDATE statement or not etc.  So my question is can it be possible that empty Excel cells be handled to be included in a SQL update statement?  Also some of the target fields in the access database are date fields and numbers so how can I handle these too?

I have tried checking if the cell is empty and assigning a null or empty value like;

```
variablename = Null or Empty or "" or 0 if an integer
```

For example

```
If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 7).value) Then
    dteEndDate = DateValue(ws.Cells(i, 7).value)
Else
    dteEndDate = Empty
End If
```

Comment: For the empty cells, can't you just pass `NULL` as their value to the `UPDATE` statement... like `UPDATE table SET name='jacob', birthdate=NULL, favcolor='red', shoesize=NULL` That way you always have the same number of fields and you can just plug in the value or NULL from the row.

Comment: Are you looping through each row individually? You can create a function to set the value to NULL if the value = "" or IsEmpty()

Comment: @WyattShipman Yes I am looping through each row.  I have updated my question with examples of trying similar to what you suggested

Comment: @JNevill Yes I have updated my question with examples of trying similar to what you suggest

Comment: Don't set the value of dteEndDate to Empty. Set it to the string: "NULL" like `dteEndDate = "NULL"`. When you stitch together your UPDATE statement you want it to actually say `SET <fieldname>=NULL`. `NULL` is a keyword for the database that means no value. It's different then `SET <fieldname>=""` which will throw not only throw an error when updating a date field, but will also leave a value in the field for non-dates when what you want is a NULL value in there.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks again for feedback.  Ah!  I see - there is a big difference between = Null and = "Null".  I will bear this in mind because I will probably have a similar issue with another table soon.  However for this current table I have found a workaround that appears to work and I will publish it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Found a different work around for dealing with this particular table.  Instead of using an UPDATE I ran a query in the relevant table for the Primary key in the table and then matched these against the rows to be updated and found their was only two records that were not to be updated.  So I renamed the Access table and removed relationships.  Then Just imported the Excel worksheet to Access as a new table but gave it the previous name of the relevant table.  Then I added the relationships and used SQL to insert the two records that were not in the worksheet